# Can I use the same backing bean for two pages?

Tags: jsf

The JSF backing bean that I have currently represents functionality to "create content". The bean corresponds to a record in the database. I have to create another html page which will allow me to update the content. Can I use the same backing bean for it? since it is allowing me to update that same created row in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You technically can. In JSF the concept "backing bean" is just a convention, and not something that JSF has inherent knowledge about or enforces in any way.

Yet, the convention is not there for nothing. In most cases having one backing bean backing one view is the best approach.

I worry though about this remark "*The bean corresponds to a record in the database.*"

To me this sounds like it's a (JPA) entity and therefor should not be a backing bean at all.

Backing beans provide functionality that is specific for a view. They call out to (EJB) services and they provide access to (JPA) entities, but they *are* neither.

Comment: So if there is a form that provides functionality to update a book database such as (book title, author) these two fields exist in the db and also in the backing bean, on start up the form should display the values stored in the database. Can I not annotate the backing bean as a jpa entity as well ? DO I need to create another pojo for the same thing ? representing a book table with fields such as author and title ?

Comment: What I am trying to say is the backing bean also has the same fields such as title and author which corresponds to the form text boxes. Can I also annotate this same class a hibernate entity and save the values in the db ?

Comment: >Can I not annotate the backing bean as a jpa entity as well  - No you can't do this. JPA entities have a distinctively different lifecycle.

Comment: >DO I need to create another pojo for the same thing? - definitely not. Do not use the scatter/gather anti-pattern (duplicating the entity as fields in the backing bean). Return the entity directly from the backing bean and bind to that. See e.g. this: http://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/browse/src/backing/UserEdit.java?name=default and the view that uses it: http://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/browse/WebContent/user_edit.xhtml?name=default

Comment: Just to add some info to this answer, a good usage for the same managed bean in several pages would be an `@ApplicationScoped` bean that contains the values for `Map<String, String>` that won't change in the application like a list of countries or marital status (of course this will depend on design though).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, there can be several "generic" managed beans in the app and a single view can use multiple of those. These kind of managed beans are then not backing beans, but just helper beans. FYI, in our apps we indeed use a managed bean with a list of countries that's used on many views too ;)